# Create and add a new array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have a while loop that pulls down values and prints them individually.  How can I get these individually printed values into one array?  Ideally I would put something in my while loop and continuously add to an array with my numeric values.

Comment: What exactly is a while loop that "pulls down values"? Where are the values coming from? How are they being retrieved? Show some code.

Comment: no such thing as array in python

Comment: could you provide an example what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a `for loop`:

```
valuesToBePulledDown = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
array=[i for i in valuesToBePulledDown]
print array
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
print [i for i in xrange(100)]
```

If you want to iterate over a specific list:

```
my_list = [4,3,2,1,5,3,2]
print [i for i in my_list]
```

Maybe you would like to do something to each value before adding it to the list:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
print [i*i for i in my_list]  # prints [1,4,9,16,25]
```

This should get you started.
However, if you are insistent on using a while loop:

```
count = 0
my_values = []
while count < 10:
    my_values.append(count)
    count += 1

print my_values  # prints [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Although, if you want to use an explicit looping construct, this particular scenario lends itself to a for loop:

```
my_values = []
for i in xrange(10):
    my_values.append(i)

print my_values  # prints [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Needless to say, as with the list comprehensions, you can use any iteratable object, not just xrange() in for loop.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you wanted to say "append" instead of "print", and "list" instead of "array".

```
valuesToBePulledDown = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
array = []
i = 0
while i<len(valuesToBePulledDown):
    array.append(i)
    print i
    i += 1
```

By the way, I would recomend you to use a for loop instead a "while", but that's what you asked for.

Comment: fyi, Python doesn't have post/pre increment/decrement, as you wrote with the i++. You would have to write i += 1 or i = i + 1.

Comment: I wrote the code without interpreting it and completely forgot that detail. Thank you!